# MVC @Url.Action directs to wrong action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, hyperlink, url.action

I have a Login page with a "Forgot Password" link, which is created using an `<a>` tag with an `href` attribute of `@Url.Action("ForgotPassword", "Login", new { Area = "Admin" })`, and for some reason this link directs me to the login page instead of the ForgotPassword page.

Does anybody have a clue as to why this is? I have been investigating and found nothing strange in my project.

Another note: the "Index" action on my Login controller gets hit, but the "ForgotPassword" action never does.

Here's the ForgotPassword action:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ForgotPassword()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Can you show yout ForgotPassword Action?

Comment: Also, what is the link that is generated? You mention the link directs you to login page, but didn't mention if the link is being generated incorrectly.

Comment: You didn't specify the [Authorize] attribute on your controller?

Comment: Try `[AllowAnonymous]` on the ForgotPassword Action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my issue was being caused by my `BaseController.cs` which all of my other controllers inherit from. It was redirecting to the login because of faulty validation logic, which I fixed.

Thank you all for the sensible suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not in @Url.Action. This is because you deny access to this action. May be you have [Authorize] attribute on your Login controller. If you don't want to delete [Authorize] attribute you can allow action in you web.config:

```
<configuration>
    ...

    <location path="Login/ForgotPassword">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>

...
</configuration>
```

Comment: @keyCrumbs I'm sorry. It is directly in <configuration>. I have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

If there is `[Authorize]` attribute in `Login` controller, move it and put it in actions which you want users can access who `isAuthorized`.